# npm install errors project on vue@2 and nuxt

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, node-modules, npm-install

I have purchased a paid template named vie from Envato market. **npm install** command gives the errors mentioned below.

---

> npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs

> npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated

> npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility

> npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.

> npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated particles.vue@2.43.1: Version 2.x is the current version, v1 is obsolete now
> npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated

> npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
> npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

> npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
> npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

> npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
> npm WARN deprecated tsparticles@1.43.1: tsParticles 2.6.0 is out, please update
> npm ERR! code 255
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data\Templates\xyz\Main_files\project_name\node_modules\swiper
> npm ERR! command failed
> npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\postinstall675294575.cmd
> npm ERR! "Love Swiper? Support Vladimir's work by donating or pledging on patreon:
> npm ERR! The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: Which template? What is it's code? No support on the place where you bought it?

Answer (score 1):

It's just warning messages (not errors) due to some outdated NPM dependencies.

You can run the [`npm outdated`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-outdated) command in your terminal to check which ones can be updated.

Then update each outdated version in your `package.json` file and run the `npm install` command again.